# Jumpy backgound image on android with jquery supersized

Tags: android, css, templates, joomla, supersized

On this joomla 2.5 test site I have a responsive template that uses a 'supersized' module to give you a toggleable background image slide show.

It works fine, except it is reported that the background jumps around allot on android and other mobile devices.

On IOS it works fine.

http://www.vossrafting.com/joom2/

Any clue how to stop this.  The plugin is set to line the image up to the top of the screen and resize it to the width..

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a solution for this. Seems to be related with the transitions between the slides/images. Opera mobile works flawless too.

To avoid the issue I did this

JS

```
var sliderSpeed = $(document).width() > 767 ? 6000 : 999999; // set time
slide_interval : sliderSpeed, // Length between transitions
```

not a solution though